# Why does adding two xtensor expressions together in template function broadcast incorrectly?

Tags: c++, templates, xtensor

Considering the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"
xt::xarray<double> arr1
  {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

xt::xarray<double> arr2
  {5.0, 6.0, 7.0};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct container{
    container(const T& t, const U& u) : a(t), b(u) {}
    T a;
    U b;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
container<T, U> make_container(const T& t, const U& u){
    return container<T,U>(t, u);
}

auto c = make_container(arr1, arr1);
std::cout << (arr1 * arr1) + arr2;

template <typename A, typename B, typename R>
auto operator+(const container<A, B>& e1, const R& e2){
    return (e1.a * e1.b) + e2;
}

std::cout << (c + arr2);
```

If we look at the code:

```
std::cout << (arr1 * arr1) + arr2;
```

It will output:

```
{  6.,  10.,  16.}
```

However, running the last line:

```
std::cout << (c + arr2);
```

Yields the following:

```
{{  6.,   9.,  14.}, {  7.,  10.,  15.}, {  8.,  11.,  16.}}
```

Why is this the case? I changed the function definition of `operator+` to the following:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename R>
auto operator+(const container<A, B>& e1, const R& e2){
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return (e1.b * e1.alpha) + e2;
}
```

And the output was a bit surprising:

```
auto operator+(const container<A, B> &, const R &) [A = xt::xarray_container<xt::uvector<double, std::allocator<double> >, xt::layout_type::row_major, xt::svector<unsigned long, 4, std::allocator<unsigned long>, true>, xt::xtensor_expression_tag>, B = xt::xarray_container<xt::uvector<double, std::allocator<double> >, xt::layout_type::row_major, xt::svector<unsigned long, 4, std::allocator<unsigned long>, true>, xt::xtensor_expression_tag>, R = double]
auto operator+(const container<A, B> &, const R &) [A = xt::xarray_container<xt::uvector<double, std::allocator<double> >, xt::layout_type::row_major, xt::svector<unsigned long, 4, std::allocator<unsigned long>, true>, xt::xtensor_expression_tag>, B = xt::xarray_container<xt::uvector<double, std::allocator<double> >, xt::layout_type::row_major, xt::svector<unsigned long, 4, std::allocator<unsigned long>, true>, xt::xtensor_expression_tag>, R = double]
auto operator+(const container<A, B> &, const R &) [A = xt::xarray_container<xt::uvector<double, std::allocator<double> >, xt::layout_type::row_major, xt::svector<unsigned long, 4, std::allocator<unsigned long>, true>, xt::xtensor_expression_tag>, B = xt::xarray_container<xt::uvector<double, std::allocator<double> >, xt::layout_type::row_major, xt::svector<unsigned long, 4, std::allocator<unsigned long>, true>, xt::xtensor_expression_tag>, R = double]
{{  6.,   9.,  14.}, {  7.,  10.,  15.}, {  8.,  11.,  16.}}
```

Why are there 3 `+` operations called in a single operation? Is there a macro being defined somewhere that's causing this behavior? The `R` type in the `operator+` gives us `double`, which should actually be `xt::xarray<double>`.

Any insights would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator+` defined in namespace `xt` takes universal references, and thus is preferred to your overload when you write `c + arr2`.

Thus this last line will return an `xfunction` whose first operand is your `container`, and the second one an `xarray`.

Now, since `container` is not an `xexpression`, inside the `xfunction` it is handled as ... an `xscalar<container>`!

Thus when you try to access the i-th element of this `xfunction`, the following operation is performed: `xscalar<container> + arr2[i]` (the `xscalar` is broadcasted). Since `xscalar<container>` is convertible to `container`, your `operator+` overload is called with `R` resolved as the `value_type` of `arr2`, that is, `double`.

The following loop illustrates this behavior:

```cpp
auto f = c + arr2;
for(auto iter = f.begin(); iter != f.end(); ++iter)
{
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

It generates the following calls of your `operator+`:

```cpp
operator+(c, arr[0]);
operator+(c, arr[1]);
operator+(c, arr[2]);
```

This is why you see 3 calls of your `operator+`.

Comment: Hi Johan, how do you suggest I overload the `operator+` in this case? If the universal reference is taking precedence over every operation, this may be very difficult to add operators on top of wrapper classes. I have yet to find a suitable template match that will have proper priority so far.

Comment: I think `xtensor` should provide a way to disable its operators for custom types, based on some template specialization defined by the user. I'll open an issue for this.